# Order item extension attributes are always last database entry

Tags: magento2, rest-api, extension-attributes, order-items

I have added extension attributes to order items, and values are successfully saved to table, when I get an order from rest API, extension attributes always show the value of last order item row for all other order items
1. Added event to load sales order
2.setting data to database
3.setting data to api from observer

Comment: please post your code and explain better your question